# Partitioning a matrix intro train and test in MATLAB in an efficient manner

Tags: matlab, partitioning

I am working a user-rating matrix `R` from real data with many users `u` in the rows and many items `i` in the columns where ratings `r(u,i)` is the rating of user `u` to item `i`. The ratings are from 1-5. I want to partition the data into two sets train (80%) and test (20%) with the following requirements:

1. Each user contains MINIMUM 6 positive ratings (positive ratings are 4,5)
2. On TEST, I need to have minimum 5 positive ratings for each user. (because it IS used for calculating recall in the evaluation section)
3. On Train, minimum 1 positive rating is required for each user.
4. While maintaining condition 2 and 3, I need the participating proportion 80-20 to be withheld.

I start the program as follows:

- For condition 1, I simply remove users with ratings less than 6.
- For condition 2 and 3, I can start from a single user. Find the items he has interacted with and find the positive ratings. Randomly put 5 ratings in the test and the rest (1 or more) in the train. Repeat this process for all users.
- This Process can work but can have two problems:

I. How do I make sure the partitioning scheme 80-20 is kept. It will not probably.

II. How can I make this process fast so I do not need to loop over users? (for example using a function like @bsxfun).

This process is done in MATLAB and I do not have and memory problem.

Thanks for your opinions in advance

Comment: So if condition 1 is true and each user already has a minimum of 6 positive ratings then condition 2 and 3 are redundant.

Comment: No, condition 1 is held however there is no guarantee that by randomly splitting the dataset, condition 2 and 3 are held. For example, it could happen that for a user, train has all 6 positive ratings and test has nothing or scenarios similar.

Comment: Are you partitioning on users or on items?

Comment: The problem is, that even if you find a way to do this partitioning, by definition, the partitioning will not be random, and therefore will invalidate the validation....

Comment: @psesudoDust: there is no condition on that. The preference however is to do it on the ratings themseleves, rather on users (rows) or items (columns) individually. Interesting remarks about 'invalidity of validation'. Unfortuntaly condition 2 and 3 are required becuase we calculate the Recall metric based upon the positive ratings only. Any ideas ? Thanks in advance